# Explain the "g" in g.Drawline (Visual C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawString(“hi!", new Font("Arial", 35), Brushes.Blue, 10, 100);

      g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 10, 150, 250, 150);
    }
```

Have an exam on C# and cant seem to find a solid answer to this question in my revision notes.

Comment: What do you mean by "explain" it? Also, this isn't a great place to ask for exam/homework help.

Comment: Perhaps you could rephrase this to be in the form of a question, not "tell me the answer." Stack Overflow is a question and answer site.

Comment: I removed the silverlight tag and added the WinForms tag. Please let me know if that was wrong.

Comment: Sorry about my poorly written question, This is also my first question on stack overflow so sorry again >_<

Thank you all for your input. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a reference to a [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) object - and it's obtained from the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.graphics.aspx) property of [`PaintEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.aspx) passed into the method. The `Graphics` object represents a context on which you can paint onto the control whose `Paint` event you're handling.

(This looks more like Windows Forms than Silverlight though...)

Answer (score 0):

While Jons answer is probably what will be expected for your test, "g" is also an example of a poorly named variable.

If the variable had been named more descriptively like:

```
Graphics drawingSurface = e.Graphics;
```

Then the code would explain itself and you probably wouldn't have needed to ask the question. :-)

```
drawingSurface.DrawString(“hi!", new Font("Arial", 35), Brushes.Blue, 10, 100);

drawingSurface.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 10, 150, 250, 150);
```

Comment: Yes I agree, my teachers notes are not the best and thank you for your input :)

Comment: In general I agree, but in particular for the Graphics object it is convention to simply refer to it as "g". Much the same that EventArgs and its derived classes as only named "e".